# Can a program detect that it is running in VirtualBox (or Wine) AND that the computer is being remotely accessed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wine

Basically I want to run a windows program on a remotely accessed Ubuntu computer and the program may be searching to see if it is being remotely accessed.  Would this be enough of a workaround if so?